# how to assign parameters to bash scripts

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm coding in C on ubuntu and debian and I'm tired of changing the compiled file from a.out to another name every time I make a program so I want to write a small script like this:

```
cc file.c 

mv a.out file.out
```

My problem is that I don't know how to change the name "file" for any other that I want. I don't know if you can have parameters in ubuntu.

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Why does your Title not seem to relate to your Question? Please use more care.

Comment: @waltinator I used to use bash files all the time to call my compiler, very similar to what the OP is looking for.  I eventually migrated to `Makefile`s to do that.  But I believe string out using bash scripts isn't such a bad start.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can have numbered *positional parameters* in a bash (or other Bourne-derived) shell script, for example

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/cc -o "$1" "$1.c"
```

which may be called as

```
./myscript file
```

to compile and link `file.c` to `file` - see for example the `Positional Parameters` section of the bash manual page (`man bash`).

---

However, if you have `make` installed, then you should simply be able to write `make file` to compile and link `file.c` to an executable `file` using default rules.

For example, given

```
$ ls
hello.c  subdir1  subdir2
```

where

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");

  return 0;
}
```

then

```
$ make hello
cc     hello.c   -o hello
$ 
$ ./hello
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do that. `-o` flag to the compiler already allows specifying output name.

**Note**:  on Linux, `cc` is a symlink to `gcc`, which is GNU C compiler

Example:

```
$ cat hello_world.c                                                            
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("%s","Hello World");
   return 0; 
}
$ gcc hello_world.c -o MyProg
$ ./MyProg
Hello World
```

---

As for scripts themselves, you can use command line arguments with `$N`, where N is integer number

```
$ cat compile_stuff.sh                                                         
#!/bin/bash
if gcc "$1"
then
    mv a.out "$2"
fi
$ ./compile_stuff.sh hello_world.c MyProg                                      
$ ./MyProg                                                                     
Hello World$
```

Answer (score 1):

`cc -o file.out`, from `man cc`, is the simple answer. For more complex software, we use `make` (see `man make`, look for `Makefile` in downloaded sources)